# lex expansion with blanks fails

Tags: regex, flex-lexer, lex

I want a rule to match everything but blanks:

```
[^ \t\n\r\f\v] {}
```

But I want to use an expansion for that:

```
BLANK [ \t\n\r\f\v]
%%
[^{BLANK}] {}
```

But the expansion fails.

I could do `[^[:space:]]`, but I want to know why the expansion doesn't work.

Why? How can I expand this?

Comment: \S does not work in lex regex (as \d, \w, …)

Comment: and ok, I could do `[^[:space:]]`, but I want to know why the expansion doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can't expand names inside a character class.

> Note that inside of a character class, all regular expression
>   operators lose their special meaning except escape (`\`) and the
>   character class operators, `-`, `]`, and, at the beginning of the
>   class, `^`.

(Quote from the [Flex manual section on Patterns](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html), near the bottom.)

Put another way, a name expansion `{name}` is a term in a regular expression. It's not macro expansion.

By the way, in most cases, the expansion of the name is surrounded by parentheses. (You can see that in the [example in the flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Definitions-Section.html).)

Comment: Ah, ok. I've read that, though thought name expansion was a lex feature, acting as a macro expansion. But it is a regex feature and trated as an operator, then. Thanks!